# Verify angle pi/4 maximizes launch range

Tags: mathematical-optimization, physics

I'm solving the equation of motion for a projectile in the x, y plane and got this:

```
R = v0^2 sin(2 theta) / g
```

where R is the range of how far the object will fly.

I'm trying to verify for any velocity `v0`, `theta = 45` would give the farthest range. How would I show that?

Comment: Remember in Mathematica, that built-in functions start with capital letters and use square brackets... So your `sin(...)` has to be `Sin[...]`. This also means you should avoid capitalizing custom variables and functions, as your `R`

Comment: This physics homework problem should be done by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[range]
range[v0_, theta_] := v0^2 Sin[2 theta]/g
Solve[{D[range[v0, theta], theta] == 0, 0 <= theta <= 90 Degree}, theta]

(* Out: {{theta -> π/4}} *)
```